# Given standard Gaussian random variables. What is the expectation of the sum of the $n$ smallest ones squared?

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, gaussian, chi-squared

We sample $m$ standard Gaussian random variables $x_i \sim N(0,1)$. Then we select the $n \leq m$ smallest ones in absolute value. Compute the expectation of $X:=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.

I know that since $x_i$ is a standard Gaussian random variable $X$ is chi-squared distributed with $n$ degrees of freedom. The expectation of a chi-squared random variable is the number of degrees of freedom, so in this case $n$. Since we are first sampling $m$ variables $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ and then choosing the $n$ smallest ones we obtain that $E[X]\leq n$, but what is it exactly?

Thank you very much for your help.

Ok: So I want to compute the first, second, ..., n-th order of statistic of a chi-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom, compute the expected values and add them together.

The cumulative distribution function of a chi-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom is given by $F(x) = Erf(\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}})$ where $Erf$ denotes the Gaussian error function and the density function is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$ Hence, the density function is

$f_{X_{(r)}}(x) = \frac{m!}{(r-1)!(m-r)!} f(x)[F(x)]^{r-1}[1-F(x)]^{m-r}$.

The expectation of the r-th order of statistics is given by $\int_0^\infty xf(x) dx = \frac{m!}{(r-1)!(m-r)!} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x/2}(erf({\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}))^{r-1} (1-erf(\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}))^{m-r}dx$

I am having problems computing this term, does someone have a further tip for me?

EDIT: The integral seems to be impossible to compute for a general $m$, although it is possible if one plugs in a specific value. Hence, I am now closing the question.

Comment: Chi squared can take values from 0 to infinity so the expectation from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: Hello, thank you. But I am taking $x_i$ between $0$ and $1$, do I still have to go to $\infty?$.

Comment: You need to be very careful with what you mean by "smallest," because if $X_i$ are standard normal, they can be negative and therefore smaller than any positive observations.  For example, if your sample is $(-1.32, -0.75, -0.31, 0.15, 0.42, 1.8)$, then the three smallest observations are $(-1.32, -0.75, -0.31)$ whose squares are *larger* than the three smallest squared observations, which would correspond to $((-0.31)^2, (0.15)^2, (0.42)^2)$.  Which one do you intend?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for pointing that out. I mean smallest in absolute value. I am going to edit the question

Comment: Why does xi between 0 and 1? If you are referring to N(0,1), it means 0 mean and 1 variance but can take any value. Or did you already know this?

Comment: Oh no, you are right. I was confused for a moment, I apologize

Comment: You can also try computing the sample from a truncated Gaussian distribution from 0 to $\infty$ and computing $E(X_{(r)}^2)$. I am not sure if it will be any easier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the expected value of the 1st order statistic, 2nd order statistic, up to nth order statistic of a chi squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom from a sample of size m, added together.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am going to do the computation and edit my question. Would you mind checking if I did understand you correctly?